# Udp readfrom until the end

Tags: c, linux, udp, client-server

Socket Used : udp

I have a client who sends 5000 bytes and a server with this code :

Client code :

```
cod = sendto (sFd, (void *) buffer, 5000, 0, (struct sockaddr *)
            &soc, sizeof (struct sockaddr_in));
```

Server code :

```
//leghtBuffer = 5000
while (lenghtBuffer > 0 )
{
 //I will insert a signal if pass more than 30 s ...
 cod = recvfrom (sFd, buffer,256 , 0, (struct sockaddr *) &clientSoc, &lungimeSocket); 

 printf("Am received %d bytes " ,cod );
 lenghtBuffer = lenghtBuffer - cod;

}
```

How can I read more than 1 time 256 bytes from this while (still using Udp socket)?

Comment: Is it not working like this? What's the problem you are facing? elaborate

Comment: I receive only the first 256 bytes , but i wanted to get more , without changing  the number of bytes from that recvfrom .

Comment: After receiving first 256 bytes, while loop terminates?

Comment: no, it will remain at `cod = recvfrom (sFd, buffer,256 , 0, (struct sockaddr *) &clientSoc, &lungimeSocket);` , i used some prints before recvfrom and it remain there

Comment: This is because UDP sends and forgets the 5000 bytes. But your call receives only 256 from those 5000. Either send and receive 256 or try send and receive for 5000 bytes in single call

Comment: 5000 bytes is too much to send in a single datagram. The generally accepted limit taking unknown routers into account is 534 bytes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UDP is a message (datagram) based transport protocol and not stream based like TCP.  Each sendto/recvfrom works in terms of complete messages.

On the sending end, each call to sendto() creates a datagram of the specified size and data, which in your case is 5000 bytes.

On the receiving end, each call to recvfrom() copies the next message in the receive buffer.  Since your datagrams are 5000 bytes, but you're only providing a 256 byte buffer, your datagram is being truncated to 256 bytes as it's copied.

The [recvfrom() OpenGroup](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xns/recvfrom.html) specification clarifies the behavior in this case:

> For message-based sockets such as SOCK_DGRAM and SOCK_SEQPACKET, the entire message must be read in a single operation. If a message is too long to fit in the supplied buffer, and MSG_PEEK is not set in the flags argument, the excess bytes are discarded.

You'll want to increase your buffer on the receive end to be 5000 bytes to account for the entire datagram